# python 2.7 - csv file pull data from 2 columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So I have a csv file and I need to find only the specific lines that match a criteria and then count how many occurrences of those lines are.

Example file:

```
col1    col2    col3

david1
david2
david3
david4

david1          sev5
david1          sev5
david1          sev4
david2          sev5
david2          sev1
david3          sev5
david3          sev2
david3          sev2
david4          sev1
```

The desired info I need is to only find lines that match for example:

```
david1 : sev5
david1 : sev4
david3 : sev2
```

And then give me a total of how many it has found.

I've searched around using dictionaries and lists but for some reason I just don't understand how they could skip over certain sections of the file and then count specific lines that match a search.

I very much still have my 'L' plates on python and some kind help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That that your actual CSV file? With no proper delimiter characters? Commonly a CSV uses commas or hard tabs for the column delimiter. Python has a `csv` package but if your CSV file isn't really a valid CSV file you're going to have a harder time parsing it.

Comment: You should also post the code you've got so far and explain specifically what part isn't working at the moment.

Comment: Hi @TomDalton, No that isnt the acual file. It is too large to post. It is an example file as mentioned. I would love to post my attempt but I have been trying all sorts of lists and dicts and looping over but I just dont know what functionality I should use to achieve my goals. I can see on the net that people use pandas to pick out certain sections of cells / columns but this wont help me as I need to pick out whatever is linked to sev5, sev4 etc etc as described. All I know is that a loop will be involved but what tools to use I dont know what is out there?? As I said... Im learning still.

Comment: Can you post the first 5-10 lines of your actual file? Even if your various tries don't work, it's hard to give you specific advice without seeing specific code. Please post one of your attempts and then we can steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @fusion1275 You could use a `collections.Counter` that counts tuples of column 1 and 3 pairs and then pick all the entries of interest afterwards.

Comment: @BlackJack thats what I need. Thank you very much. I will read up more on this and post how I am getting on.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
list_of_line = []

result1 = []
result2 = []
result3 = []

file.csv = open("some.csv","r")

for l in file.csv:
    l = l.split(" ")
    for i in l:
        x = i[2]
        if x == "sev5":
            result1.append(x)
        if x == "sev4":
            result.append(x)

print len(result1)

print len(result2)
```